# Is there a way to increase parse 15 seconds cloud job limit?

Tags: parse-platform

My cloud job on parse runs beyond 15 seconds. So till 15 seconds it processes x records out of n records, remaining (n-x) records are not processed. We changed the logic to pick up one by one record and get the job done, but this logic will increase the traffic of cloud job.
1. is there a way out to stop the cloud job after n records are processed? currently you have to run the job everytime on specific day till all records are processed, because there is no way out in parse to run the job for specified time duration; you have to schedule the job.
or
2. is there a way out to increase the 15 seconds job limit by anyway?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't increase the limit. But you could device a way of splitting the job into smaller jobs.

Off the top of my head: The first job creates an array of all objectIds to be handled. It grabs i.e. the first 500 ids and stores the rest in a "job config" record of some sorts, and handles the 500 objects itself.

Job 2 is scheduled to start later than the first job and grabs the next 500 IDs, removes them from the array and stores the config job record, and then handles its 500 object.

Job 3 is scheduled after job 2 etc... you get the point.

If you describe your use case with more details, maybe there are other less hacky solutions as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Lonely Penguin.. we are using the same way to get along with these 15 seconds issue.. but as you mentioned we can not change the the limit of 15 seconds